# jQuery UI: how to apply the Progressbar to a webpage?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar, loading

How would you apply the jQuery UI **Progressbar** to a website's **loading progress** (during the *initial* loading)?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: If its for normal pages you can fake it See these tutorials --- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_progressbar.htm -- if your pages have images then you will need to do some Math, for example 10 images on a page is 10% scale on the progress bar for each image loaded to the page. In that case you will need to know when each image has loaded so you can increase the bar -- you can use a plugging called images loaded --- http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Comment: You mean something like this. http://onextrapixel.com/examples/youtube-like-ajax-loading-bar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Pace.js Javascript Library](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) for progress bar. you could write code like this at the very top level of your code:

```
<link href='pace.css' rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">
    paceOptions = {
        ajax: false,
        document: true,
        eventLag: false,
        elements: {
            selectors: ['body']
        }
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pace.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Pace seems to be too fast for my needs. I want to be able to change the rate *pseudo-realistically*, like I do here: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbishop017/L5V6F/

Comment: @017Bluefield Okay..Den you can go with you fiddle  if it works for you. :)

Comment: Actually, is there anyway to slow it down, at least?

Comment: Slow down in what sense ? it runs as per your document load.

Comment: Well, Tasos said that I can fake it. I know I can do it with this kind of code: `if (val < 100) { timeoutHook = setTimeout(progress, 1); if (val >= 30) {begin.progressbar("value", val + 0.1);} if (val >= 50) {begin.progressbar("value", val + 0.6);} … }`